# Berry's curvature equation

Tags: geometry, quantum-mechanics

The following textbook Heisenberg's Quantum Mechanics shows an example of calculating Berry's curvature (top page on pg 518). It led to a following equation

[1]
$$
V_{m} = {- 1 \over B^2 } * i * \sum { (<m,B|S|n,B>  ∧  <n,B|S|m,B>) \over A^2}
$$

the textbook claims that we add the term m = n since
$$ <m|S|m>  ∧  <m|S|m> = 0 $$
  then the above equation simplifies to

[2]
$$
V_{m} = {- 1 \over B^2 } * i * \sum { (<m,B|S ∧ S|m,B>) \over A^2}
$$

The symbol ∧ stands for 'and' in logic or cross product in mathematics.

My question is how the author derived that claim and how it led to that equation [2] from equation [1] ?

My reasoning is that 
$$ |n,B> ∧ <n,B| = 1$$

because both are true.  Furthermore 1 = 1 ∧ 1 then it leads to equation [2].  However, I believe my reasoning is to weak or invalid and I wondered if there is a better alternative to explain author's claim. note that there is bra > and ket < notation used here.
Thanks.